# Counting leading zeros

Tags: python, counting, leading-zero

I have a basic function:

```
    return len(a) - len(str(int(a)))
```

When this is run against the value of:  `0000`
It returns 3 rather than 4.

I really do not understand why, can someone please clarify?

Comment: It returns 3 because your test number is `0000`, which is `0` with 3 leading zeros.

Comment: That statement makes sense, but how does my code decide not to count the first 0.
I thought it compares the value of the string compared to the value of the other string after its been converted to an int (and back)

Comment: ```len(a) = 4``` in your case and ```len(int(a)) = 1``` so ```4-1=3```

Comment: Maybe should you test `int(a)` value before and a specific calculation for 0

Comment: @Christophe I am trying that currently but a little cloudy on where to go with it, i tried ``` if a +1 = 1 ``` but unsure how to count the zeros, perhaps ``` isnumeric ```

Comment: what about `if int(a) == 0`?

Comment: @NicoAdrian When it runs against 001 it returns 2 as expected

Comment: @DeanTaler Is that because all ints (000 or 00000000) change to 0?

Comment: @ChristAHFER yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
if int(a) == 0:
    nb_zeros = len(a)
else:
    nb_zeros = len(a) - len(str(int(a)))

print(nb_zeros)
```